# Naming Convention: UserGroup vs Group - TaskType vs Type

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, naming-conventions

Usually using word `Group` as a model name is nice and easy, but my applicatoin is just getting little bit bigger and I was thinking about using `UserGroup`. This solves my problem, On the other hand making it 2 words creates code that is not visually satisfying `@user.user_group` or `task.task_type` .

What would be the other disadvantages of using names like these other than that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think we've all been there. My 2 cents:

- `UserGroup`. In a web application most of the times a *group* is a group of users, so you may safely drop the `User`.
- `TaskType`. `Type` is too general a name, so I'd compromise: call the class `TaskType` but use `types` as the association name so you can write the arguably nicer `some_task.types`:

  ```
  class Task
    has_many :types, :class_name => :TaskType
    ...
  end
  ```